# Powershell script works in one .NET Solution, not another

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using a C# library I [found](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/psoutlooklive) that runs some remote Powershell scripts for Outlook Live. As a proof-of-concept that it works, I made a unit test that I can run (and step through for debugging) which merely calls a `public static` method inside this library which behind the scenes opens a remote Powershell session and runs a script.

This works just great in one of our Solutions, but it does not work when I run it in another Solution, even though both Solutions have the same two projects and test classes in them.. One Solution gives me an exception

> There were errors in loading the format data file: 
>   Microsoft.PowerShell, , `C:\Users\xxxx.xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_8c84e626-4399-420b-b874-9feeb3b1e195_tjlxhzzr.rlr\tmp_8c84e626-4399-420b-b874-9feeb3b1e195_tjlxhzzr.rlr.format.ps1xml` : File skipped because of the following validation exception: File `C:\Users\xxxx.xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_8c84e626-4399-420b-b874-9feeb3b1e195_tjlxhzzr.rlr\tmp_8c84e626-4399-420b-b874-9feeb3b1e195_tjlxhzzr.rlr.format.ps1xml` cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details..

One attempt I made was to modify the `PSCommand` inside the C# library to have `Unrestricted` set and that did not solve the problem. However, if I open up the x86 Powershell and run `set-executionpolicy Unrestricted` my test will run in both Solutions. Changing the execution policy in the x64 version of Powershell had no effect on either Solution.

Is there some type of setting for permissions that is specific to a Solution? Neither the Web.Config or Global.asax should matter since I'm not loading any pages, so I don't know what else would take effect since I'm running the same unit test in both solutions with the same test runner (Testdriven.Net).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run as administrator usually sets hklm otherwise it is set in hkcu
on a 64bit OS you need to run Set-ExecutionPolicy for 32bit and 64bit PSH separately

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell

to check
cd "hklm:\Software\Microsoft\Powershell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft Powershell"
dir

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. I'm aware that you have to set execution policy separately as I mentioned I have done so in my question. I'm also not running Powershell interactively, so I don't have a run as administrator option in that sense. I am using C# code that calls Powershell.